# how to get hidden value from html and pass to next page

Tags: php, ajax

**This is my code**

**Html Code**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['id']))
    {
    $Eventid=$_POST['id'];
    }
    ?>
<input name="rating" value="0" id="rating_star"  type="hidden" postID="'.$Eventid.'" />
<div class="overall-rating" >(Average Rating <span id="avgrat">'.$ratingRow['average_rating'].'</span>
    Based on <span id="totalrat">'. $ratingRow['rating_number'] .'</span>  rating)</span></div></div>
```

**Ajax**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
$(function() {
    $("#rating_star").spaceo_rating_widget({
        starLength: '5',
        initialValue: '',
        callbackFunctionName: 'processRating',
        imageDirectory: 'img/',
        inputAttr: 'post_id'
    });
});


function processRating(val, attrVal){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'rating.php',
        data: 'post_id=1&points='+val,
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'ok') {
                alert('You have rated '+val+' to SPACE-O');
                $('#avgrat').text(data.average_rating);
                $('#totalrat').text(data.rating_number);
            }else{
                alert('please after some time.');
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#rating_star").val()`

Comment: can you please add the code

Comment: You have to pass it by AJAX?

Comment: Finally, it is not important if the input is hidden or not. You can get it normally.

Comment: @HasH sir i want to save the $eventid in database so that every event must have own ratings

Comment: @KubiRoazhon sir okay..so how can i get this value in ajax and pass it to next page like iam doing in the code  --data: 'post_id=1&points='+val,... here iam giving value 1 but i want to give here $Eventid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the value using the id of the element like I've added it. I've also modified the `data` property in your `Ajax` call.

```
function processRating(val, attrVal){
    var raisingStar = $('#rating_star').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'rating.php',
        data: {"post_id":1,"points":val,"raising_star":raisingStar}
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'ok') {
                alert('You have rated '+val+' to SPACE-O');
                $('#avgrat').text(data.average_rating);
                $('#totalrat').text(data.rating_number);
            }else{
                alert('please after some time.');
            }
        }
    });
}
```